# Android Java memory usage with AdMob

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management

I am experience som major memory issues with my projekt. If you could throw some advice for me that would be really helpfull.. I'll try to explain my whole usage.

In the main activity, the first thing I do is setting upp the AdMob banners. Which seems to use ALOT of memory. This is my whole onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mGameView = new GameView(this, getAssets());

    ActivityManager am = ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
    mGameView.setMemoryLimit(am.getMemoryClass());        

    mLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    mLayout.addView(mGameView);        

    if(mGameView.getMemoryLimit() > 40 && !mGameView.isFullVersion())
    {
        mAdView = new AdView(mThis, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxx");
        mAdRequest = new AdRequest();
        mAdView.loadAd(mAdRequest);
        mAdRequest = null;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mAdView.setLayoutParams(lp);                
        mLayout.addView(mAdView);           
    }

    setContentView(mLayout);

    hideBannerAd();
}
```

As I have googled alot, the AdMob code seems to leak memory so I try to keep it alive the whole lifetime of the app and only showing it on loadingscreens.

At this point I am using maybe 10-15mb memory JUST FOR THE ADS.

I have grouped all bitmaps used by Menu and Gameplay. Which means I only load the the menu bitmaps when I show the menu and then recycle and delete the reference of the old bitmaps before loading the new ones.

During the loading process I check how much percent of memory I have left and only continue to load bitmaps if the percent is less than 90%.

I calculate the memory percent by:

```
Debug.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
percent = (float) (memoryInfo.getTotalPss() / 1024.0) / (float) mGameView.getMemoryLimit() * 100;
```

tge memoryLimit comes from earlier mentioned activity:

```
ActivityManager am = ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
mGameView.setMemoryLimit(am.getMemoryClass());
```

As you saw in the activity I am only showing ads for devices with more than 40mb memory. But I am using about 20mb for the project WITHOUT ADS.

Another problem I have encountered is with devices that share memory with other applications. Like if their memory limit is 64 but is still using like 40-50 from elsewhere than my app. Can I somehow request that memory to be cleared?

Am I doing someting wrong because this is really getting to my nerves. I mean I have seen apps using like 2-5 ads at the same time..

Can I somehow manage this better?